# CakePHP 2 application works fine locally, but comes back with database errors when live?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, deployment

I've been working on a CakePHP application over the last few months and have finally put it live on a test server on the internet. It has been fairly easy to put it up and live, and it works to a point.

There is a database connection to the server and the app can retrieve data from the database. However, some pages are now returning SQL errors along the lines of:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'personel.companyid' in 'where clause'
```

I thought it might be an error with the application so I rechecked my local copy and the local copy works fine. I then checked the database schema on the test server to see if the column actually exists in all of the cases where I've received these errors. The columns that are apparently unknown are there and include a carbon copy of my local database.

I'm confused about why this is occurring. The only thing that is different between my local machine and my test server is that I developed the site locally on a Windows computer under an XAMPP set up and the test server runs on a Linux (CentOS) VPS.

Is there anything else that could be causing this problem?

**EDIT:***
These are two of the queries that are failing:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'personel.companyid' in 'where clause'

SQL Query: SELECT `Personel`.`id`, `Personel`.`firstname`, `Personel`.`surname`, `Personel`.`email`, `Personel`.`companyid`, `Personel`.`accesslevel`, `Personel`.`poc`, `Personel`.`password`, `Personel`.`telephone`, `Accesslevel`.`id`, `Accesslevel`.`acclevname` FROM `personel` AS `Personel` LEFT JOIN `accesslevels` AS `Accesslevel` ON (`Personel`.`accesslevel` = `Accesslevel`.`id`) WHERE `personel`.`companyid` = 1
```

And this one:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'personel.companyid' in 'where clause'

SQL Query: SELECT `Personel`.`id`, `Personel`.`firstname`, `Personel`.`surname`, `Personel`.`email`, `Personel`.`companyid`, `Personel`.`accesslevel`, `Personel`.`poc`, `Personel`.`password`, `Personel`.`telephone`, `Accesslevel`.`id`, `Accesslevel`.`acclevname` FROM `personel` AS `Personel` LEFT JOIN `accesslevels` AS `Accesslevel` ON (`Personel`.`accesslevel` = `Accesslevel`.`id`) WHERE `personel`.`companyid` = 1
```

Comment: can you find the query that is failing?

Comment: There are several queries, I will update the answer with two of the main ones.

Comment: is it that the query is case-sensitive? try WHERE `Personel`.`companyid` = 1 and see if it works

Comment: I've just went through one of the pages and changed them to have capital letters and it's solved the issue. It's strange how it worked in local but not on the test server? If you put that as an answer I'll mark it off.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the query is case-sensitive. Try using upper-case `Personel` everywhere.

Refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html. The first paragraph will explain that MySQL is case-sensitive on Unix and not on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for that, why would it work locally though but not on a live system?

Comment: As it says in the MySQL reference link, MySQL is case-sensitive on Unix and not on Windows.